# Nestjs project fails to start because it reads files outside of it's module

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

[image]
My Nestjs Project fails to start because it indexes other node projects out of its own project folder.

Comment: If you're looking for help you're going to need to post more details. Where are these files? Do you have `src` in any of your imports? `tsconfig.json`? How are you starting your project? `start:dev` or `start`? Does the `build` phase pass? There's too much unknown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your configuration and thus your entity file does not recognize `src/` as part of your application.

Try replacing `src/directors/director.entity` inside your `movies.entity.ts` with relative path such as `../../directors/director.entity` and see what happens then.